# Select statement to return internally linked rows of a single table

Tags: mysql

```
-------------------------
|  ID   | LINK  |  NOM  |
-------------------------
|  05   |  00   |  BOB  |
|  07   |  05   |  SAM  |
|  08   |  05   |  TIM  |
|  10   |  08   |  ALF  |
|  13   |  05   |  DOC  |
|  25   |  08   |  JIM  |
|  26   |  07   |  IAN  |
|  28   |  25   |  LOU  |
-------------------------
```

I wish to write a SELECT statement that given the table above returns a result-set similar to those below.

For example, an (as yet incomplete) query like:

```
SELECT ID, NOM FROM ABOVE_TABLE WHERE NOM='ALF'
```

will return the values:

```
10, ALF
08, TIM
05, BOB
```

whereas the query:

```
SELECT ID, NOM FROM ABOVE_TABLE WHERE NOM='LOU'
```

will return the values.

```
28, LOU
25, JIM
08, TIM
05, BOB
```

and:

```
SELECT ID, NOM FROM ABOVE_TABLE WHERE NOM='JIM'
```

will return the values.

```
25, JIM
08, TIM
05, BOB
```

and finally:

```
SELECT ID, NOM FROM ABOVE_TABLE WHERE NOM='IAN'
```

will return the values.

```
26, IAN
07, SAM
05, BOB
```

---

Is such a SELECT statement possible and what form would it take?

Comment: This looks like you want a recursive query.

Answer (score 0):

```
To work this query it should be ID greater than LINK. SO here get table 
as ID descending order.

select t.ID as ID, @pv:=t.LINK as LINK 
from (select ID,LINK from [ABOVE_TABLE] order by ID desc) t
join
(select @pv:=(select ID from [ABOVE_TABLE] WHERE NOM='ALF'))tmp
where t.ID=@pv;
```